# Starting Android activity gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have an activity, LookingForGPS, that starts another activity, Run. After starting Run, LookingForGPS doesn't finish, but rather continually updates some TextViews in Run:

```
Run run = new Run();
if(runHasBeenStarted)run.getAndSetValues(someParameters, this);
```

To my understanding, `this` returns the LookingForGPS activity. However, after a while (when the parameters are a certain value) I want to start a new activity, PostRun. The following method is called from the Run instance's getAndSetValues:

```
private void killEverythingAndProceed(Context context){
    Intent finishRun = new Intent(context, PostRun.class);
    //putting some extras into the intent
    startActivity(finishRun);
}
```

I then get a NullPointerException at the line of startActivity:

```
11-17 08:34:33.647    2472-2472/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: lv.rv1g.kj0112.forward, PID: 2472
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
        at lv.rv1g.kj0112.forward.Run.killEverythingAndProceed(Run.java:143)
        at lv.rv1g.kj0112.forward.Run.getAndSetValues(Run.java:88)
        at lv.rv1g.kj0112.forward.LookingForGPS.onLocationChanged(LookingForGPS.java:100)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:279)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:208)
        at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:224)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing horribly wrong? I guess it's my lack of knowledge about object-oriented programming that's causing this. It's not the extras causing it, and the context should be correct as well, as it works for another method from the same instance.

Edit: detailed explanation

The LookingForGPS activity has a LocationManager (not using a service because it has some limitations that are too complicated for me to work around). Each time `onLocationChanged` is called, the `Run` activity is instantiated (I check whether it has actually been started first, it gets started by the user independetly of the LocationManager), and the `getAndSetValues` method inside `Run` is called, giving a bunch of parameters. `getAndSetValues` then performs some calculations and updates some `TextViews` in  the `Run` activity (which all works fine). A calculation is also performed to see whether a certain condition has been met. If it has been, the `postRun` activity is supposed to be started, which is when I run into the exception above.

Comment: Can you post your whole code, because it's too hard to find the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Android-Developer there's just a lot of calculations really, the important part I described in my edit. I can post the code if you think it'd help, but I don't think it would.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

> ```
> Run run = new Run();
> ```

Looks like `Run` is an `Activity`. Never instantiate activities with `new` - you cannot use activities instantiated such way for anything you'd want to use an activity for. For example, to be used as a `Context` for `startActivity()`.

Either use an `Activity` instance that has been set up by the system for you, or use an `Intent` to launch a new activity instance.

Comment: If you look at the stacktrace the NullPointer is thrown in `killEverythingAndProceed` so I guess more like `context` variable is null.

Comment: It is an Activity indeed. How do I use the `Activity` instance?

Comment: @Android-Developer That would throw earlier in `Intent` constructor if `context` was null.

Comment: @Karl Depends on what you actuallu want to do. There's not enough context (sic) in the question to offer specific guidance other than not to instantiate activities with `new`.

Comment: @laalto I updated the question with some additional information, hope that'd be more helpful.